# Problem in camera activities in ios4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapture

hi so far i have used  UIImagePickerController  for camera activities in IOS3. But in IOS4 the  ImagePickerController is  not working properly. When i tried to capture  image it shows either a  white image or else the app gets crashed often.

So i started using the AVCapture device for my camera  activities. In  this too i started facing new problems. When i capture  the image in  landscape the image preview shows the image to be portrait  and vice  versa. And some times it shows memory level warning.

Both  the UIImagePickerController and the AVCapture are making  problems. I  want to know how to solve these problems. Else is there any  other way  to handle camera activities in IOS4.

Please help me friends.....

Comment: Why don't you be specific with the problems you are facing?? What did the error say?

Comment: i say that when i use AVCapture device, the image captured in landscape, saves the image to be portrait and vice versa. And some times it shows memory level warning.

Comment: now i want to know how to get my captured images in ios4

Comment: Post what you were doing for both approaches. I don't think there is any other way for camera-related activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to enable the user to take photos, UIImagePickerController is the way to go. AVFoundation is quite low level and requires you to handle a lot of things yourself (e.g. compensating for the device orientation).

I've used UIImagePickerController extensively on iOS 4 and it works just fine for me. I suspect the white image/crashing problems are due to something else in your code. If you post a few code snippets we can try to figure out what's going on.